# Cannot create phar

Tags: php, phar

I am trying to learn how to create phars and i am getting this error and have no  clue how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Cannot create phar '/myapp/build/myapp.phar', file extension (or combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist' in /Volumes/www/vhosts/myapp/create-phar.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /Volumes/www/vhosts/myapp/create-phar.php(11): Phar->__construct('/myapp/build/my...', 256, 'myapp.phar')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Volumes/www/vhosts/myapp/create-phar.php on line 11
```

I am following the code form this page: [packaging your app with phar](http://www.sitepoint.com/packaging-your-apps-with-phar/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the full path for windows like

```
$srcRoot = getcwd() . '/src';
$buildRoot = getcwd() . '/build';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been following the same article and the problem are the paths or how they are defined in the first couple of lines, here is what I did:

```
    $srcRoot = "src/";
    $buildRoot = "build/";
```

This solution is for Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS